# How to split a Sinatra app with different scopes?

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

I'm splitting a large Sinatra file into different files using registers. This is one way to have a [modular Sinatra app using extensions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html).

I'm ending up with something like the following code:

```
MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register OneRegister
  register SecondRegister
end
```

---

```
module OneRegister
  def self.registered(app)
    app.helpers OneRegisterHelper

    app.get "/one-endpoint" do
      do_stuff
    end
  end

  module OneRegisterHelper
    def do_stuff
      # Some code
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
module SecondRegister
  def self.registered(app)
    app.helpers SecondRegisterHelper

    app.get "/second-endpoint" do
      do_stuff
    end
  end

  module SecondRegisterHelper
    def do_stuff
      # Different code
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is how Sinatra works with registers and helpers. Every time I create a new helper for a register I'm polluting the main Sinatra app scope with the methods in the helpers.

So, the method `do_stuff` is going to be overwritten by the `SecondRegisterHelper` (this is how Ruby works when including a module) but I'd like to have different implementations for the methods without worry if I'm using the same method name or a different one (image an app with 25 registers with small methods in each one).

Basically, I'd like to have different registers with private methods because I usually write very small private methods with a single responsibility. Any ideas, how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is achievable in the way you are trying. If you have methods with similar names in different modules mixed into a single class the last just wins.

So in this case I would create a [modular app](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) combined with a config.ru to setup your application.

```
class OneRegister < Sinatra::Base
    # helpers here
end

class SecondRegister < Sinatra::Base
    # helpers here
end
```

In config.ru

```
app = Rack::URLMap.new(
  '/one-endpoint' => OneRegister,
  '/second-endpoint' => TwoRegister 
)

run app
```

No you helpers are scoped to a single class.